# How is this type of polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^N (x-i)$ called?

Tags: polynomials

How is this type of polynomial $\prod_{i}^N (x-i)$ called? 
$N$ is an arbitrary integer.

Is there a well-known property?
It would be nice to get to know that.

Comment: [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

Comment: @achillehui Sorry, how is that related?

Comment: @gimusi The falling factorial $(x)_n  = \prod_{k=1}^n (x-k+1)$. The polynomial at hand is simply $(x-1)_N$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the unique monic polynomial wih degree $N$ and exactly $N$ integer roots $x=1,2,\ldots,N$.